# If condition in table tag

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo

I am using Spring Roo. There is `table:table` and `table:column` tags.

```
<table:table data="${memberDetails}" id="memberDetail" delete="false"
                 create="false"
                 update="false" show="false" paginationFlag="false"
                 path="" typeIdFieldName="instanceId"
                 z="40I0ZgJoR5iBRXkYGHvl959736E=">
    <table:column id="customer" property="user.name"/> 
</table:table>
```

How do I put check for `null` or empty if property `user.name` is not empty? If it's empty I wish to address other property there.

Comment: Try `${not empty user.name ? user.name : 'Bob'}`

Comment: Florent Thank you so much for your reply. I tried what you suggested, But that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
<c:if test="${user.name =='null'}" >
 <table:column id="customer" property="user.name"/> 
</c:if>
```

Or you can use

```
 <c:if test="${not empty user.name}">
       <table:column id="customer" property="user.name"/> 
    </c:if>
```

Comment: Sajith  It seems you have not got what trouble actually I'm facing.
Actually that 'user.name' property is sub-property of objects which are inside 'memberDetails' List or Set object (See my table tag's 'data' attribute )

Comment: then also you can check this.